# unable to create sales tax on qbo api explorer

Tags: quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

unable to create sales tax on qbo api explorer.
i tried some ways but i can't create.
https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/develop/tutorials/manage-sales-tax-for-non-us-locales#overriding-sales-tax

```
 {
      "Line": [
        {
          "Description": "Pest Control Services", 
          "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail", 
          "SalesItemLineDetail": {
            "TaxCodeRef": {
              "value": "NON"
            }, 
            "Qty": 1, 
            "UnitPrice": 35, 
            "ItemRef": {
              "name": "Pest Control", 
              "value": "10"
            }
          }, 
          "LineNum": 1, 
          "Amount": 35.0, 
          "Id": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
```